# C# Site Map Authentication to host failed Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

When I use the sitemap in the ASP.net to create a tree view or siteMapPath in my web site, I encountered such exception which is related to the configuration:

> Authentication to host '' for user '' using method
>   'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user
>   ''@'DESKTOP-54CAR3Q' (using password: NO)

[image]]

this is the error code:

```
<siteMap>
  <providers>
   <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's a good idea to mess around with `machine.config` file. You probably won't have access to it in a typical production server anyway.

A neater solution would be to add `<clear />` at the beginning of the `<providers>` section; like this

```
<providers>
    <clear />
    <!-- add your own provider(s) -->
</providers>
```

You can also specify a default provider; like this (I've used an example provider):

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="DefaultSiteMap" enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DefaultSiteMap" siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" 
             type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" 
             description="My Preferred SiteMap Provider" 
             securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
    </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

And finally I got a solution from [solution](http://gokuldaspalapatta.blogspot.sg/2015/07/parser-error-message-authentication-to.html)

which guide me to commented the tag in machine.config in the path of 
*"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\ machine. config"*

and just commented on the code

```
<providers>
 <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/"/>
</providers>
```

I do not know why, but it works on my PC and laptop anyway